# How to track adaptive joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

Query Store is unable to capture information about adaptive queries because adaptive plans change on every execution.

I couldn't find an event to capture adaptative query plan execution, is there any event for that?

I tried to create a session to capture query_post_execution_showplan and filter showplan_xml to capture only adaptative queries, but there isn't a pred_compare for xml fields, so it's impossible to filter the showplan_xml field, I would need to capture the showplan_xml for all the queries being executed and filter later, that's not a good solution.

So, the main question: How can I track adaptative joins in a way that allows me to identify how many executions are using nested join and how many are using hash joins?